# React emotion is not working properly in Server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, emotion, pro-components

I am using react emotion library for styling, the styling is working properly when the application is not server side rendered but it gives styling problems when it is server side rendered. Do I need to do additional configrations for emotion with react for it to work properly with react when server side rendered?

This is how I have implemented emotion with react, is there any implementation issue?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client/react/react.cjs';
import { getDataFromTree } from '@apollo/client/react/ssr/ssr.cjs';
import { Html } from './ssr/html';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { logger } from '@cdm-logger/server';
import { ChunkExtractor } from '@loadable/server';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import createEmotionServer from '@emotion/server/create-instance'
import { createClientContainer } from '../config/client.service';
import { createReduxStore } from '../config/redux-config';
import publicEnv from '../config/public-config';
import clientModules, { MainRoute } from '../modules';

let assetMap;
const key = 'custom';
const cache = createCache({ key });
const { extractCritical, extractCriticalToChunks, constructStyleTagsFromChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache);
async function renderServerSide(req, res) {
    try {
        const { apolloClient: client } = createClientContainer();

        let context: { pageNotFound?: boolean; url?: string } = { pageNotFound: false };
        const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [req.url] });
        const { store } = createReduxStore(history);
        const App = () =>
            clientModules.getWrappedRoot(
                // tslint:disable-next-line:jsx-wrap-multiline
                <ReduxProvider store={store}>
                    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                        <CacheProvider value={cache}>
                            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                                <MainRoute />
                            </StaticRouter>
                        </CacheProvider>
                    </ApolloProvider>
                </ReduxProvider>,
                req,
            );

        await getDataFromTree(App);
        if (context.pageNotFound === true) {
            res.status(404);
        } else {
            res.status(200);
        }
        const extractor = new ChunkExtractor({
            statsFile: path.resolve(__FRONTEND_BUILD_DIR__, 'loadable-stats.json'),
            entrypoints: ['index'],
            publicPath: !__DEV__ && __CDN_URL__ ? __CDN_URL__ : '/',
        });
        // Wrap your application using "collectChunks"
        const JSX = extractor.collectChunks(App);
        const content = extractCritical(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(JSX));


        const chunks = extractCriticalToChunks(JSX)

        const appStyles = constructStyleTagsFromChunks(chunks)

        // We need to tell Helmet to compute the right meta tags, title, and such.
        const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic(); // Avoid memory leak while tracking mounted instances
        if (context.url) {
            res.writeHead(301, { Location: context.url });
            res.end();
        } else {
            if (__DEV__ || !assetMap) {
                assetMap = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__FRONTEND_BUILD_DIR__, 'assets.json')).toString());
            }
            const apolloState = Object.assign({}, client.extract());
            const reduxState = Object.assign({}, store.getState());
            const env = {
                ...publicEnv,
            };
            const page = (
                <Html
                    content={content}
                    headElements={[
                        ...extractor.getScriptElements(),
                        ...extractor.getLinkElements(),
                        ...extractor.getStyleElements(),
                    ]}
                    state={apolloState}
                    assetMap={assetMap}
                    helmet={helmet}
                    styleSheet={appStyles}
                    env={env}
                    reduxState={reduxState}
                    scriptsInserts={clientModules.scriptsInserts}
                    stylesInserts={clientModules.stylesInserts}
                />
            );
            res.send(`<!doctype html>\n${ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(page)}`);
            res.end();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('SERVER SIDE RENDER failed due to (%j) ', err.message);
        logger.debug(err);
    }
}
export const websiteMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (req.path.indexOf('.') < 0 && __SSR__) {
            return await renderServerSide(req, res);
        } else if (req.path.indexOf('.') < 0 && !__SSR__ && req.method === 'GET' && !__DEV__) {
            logger.debug('FRONEND_BUILD_DIR with index.html');
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__FRONTEND_BUILD_DIR__, 'index.html'));
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('RENDERING ERROR:', e);
        return next(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to include the error text or some other information or no one will be able to answer this probably.

Answer (score 1):

The code implementation looks fine. One possible issue might be the version of `@emotion/server` and `@emotion/react` you are using, make sure they are compatible with each other. Also, check if you have properly setup the cache object with `createCache` and passed the cache object to `CacheProvider`. You should also ensure that `getDataFromTree` is being awaited so that all data is loaded before sending the response.

Comment: do we need to wrap with `<ChakraProvider>` for `<MainRoute/>`